# Where do I code Dynamically created android buttons and how do I pass value's to the listeners

Tags: android, button, android-intent, dynamic, onclicklistener

So I am creating Dynamically Allocated Buttons. I want to query my database and based on the table the user selects (which are the dynamic buttons) a new activity will open that the user can work with the specified table.

```
        protected void createButtons(){
    // dynamically created buttons work just need to
    LinearLayout scrViewButLay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.scrollViewLinLay);
    scrViewButLay.removeAllViews();
    ArrayList<String> tanks = new ArrayList<String>();
    tanks = dbHand.getTableList();
    Button[] tankButtons = new Button[tanks.size()];
    Log.i("DB_Tag", "DB Size = " + tanks.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < tanks.size(); i++){
        Log.i("DB_NAME_TAG", tanks.get(i));
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < tanks.size(); index++) {
        tankButtons[index] = new Button(this); 
        tankButtons[index].setText(tanks.get(index));
        scrViewButLay.addView(tankButtons[index]);
        tankButtons[index].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Each buttons specific event
                /*
                 * Left off here
                 */
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainAquariumActivity.this, ProfilesOptionsScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                //How would I send tanks.get(index) to the new ProfilesOptionsScreen
            }
        });
    }

    // end of dynamically allocated buttons
}
```

I am assuming that you have to dynamically create the onClickListeners along with creating the buttons. Is there a simpler solution to this?

Comment: you should be using an AdapterView (ListView, GridView etc) and populating it with a CursorAdapter.

Comment: If you have an example I'd greatly appreciate it. I'm researching AdapterView now to see how to apply it to my situation. Thanks a lot @FoamyGuy